# How to change the operation in a subprogram in c#?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I wrote a code that makes a picturebox move when I click on a button. For example, the right button uses this code:

```
    private void btnRight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //move right
    if (stopThePlayer == true)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        x = x + speed;
        RightBoundary();
        MovingSubprograms();
    }
}
```

Don't worry about the subprograms. All I want  to know is is there a way that I can only change `x = x + speed;` part. For example, in the left button, I want to make it `x = x - speed`. So basically I'll just create a subprogram and only change that code. Is that possible? Thanks.

Comment: location property is a point which is basically a coordinate.  so create a new point from current location add and substract x as per functionality and set the location property to that point simple

Comment: You will not create a "subprogram".  You will create another event handler that will handle the btnLeft_Click event and will do what you are saying (all the same code except with `x = x - speed`.  But don't actually repeat the code, put it in a separate function... And of course, that takes you to @JohnKoerner answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to create a function that accepts a parameter of what you want to change:

```
private void MovePlayer(int offset)
{
    //move right
    if (stopThePlayer == true)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        x = x + offset;
        RightBoundary();
        MovingSubprograms();
    }
}

private void btnRight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MovePlayer(speed);
}

private void btnLeft_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MovePlayer(speed*-1);
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!